# are lib files handled differently in Rails 3 versus Rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following which worked in Rails 2.3.8:

/lib/trimmer.rb

I use it in my Contact model as follows:

```
   include Trimmer #lib module to trim blank spaces in input
```

But I get this error:

uninitialized constant Contact::Trimmer

I'm guessing lib files are handled differently, but not sure what to change?

```
  1 module Trimmer
  2   # Make a class method available to define space-trimming behavior.
  3   def self.included base
  4     base.extend(ClassMethods)
  5   end
  6 
  7   module ClassMethods
  8     # Register a before-validation handler for the given fields to
  9     # trim leading and trailing spaces.
 10     def trimmed_fields *field_list
 11       before_validation do |model|
 12         field_list.each do |n|
 13           model[n] = model[n].strip if model[n].respond_to?('strip')
 14         end
 15       end
 16     end
 17   end
 18 end
```

I think I figured it out...validate?

I have to use require 'trimmer.rb' because in Rails 3, the lib files have to be explicitly required.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lib directory isn't loaded by default in rails 3.

You need to add this:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

To your `application.rb` file.

Then it should work.